# How do I keep my ul element from disappearing when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Javascript Events</title



<style>
ul {
margin:0px auto;
width:700px;
height:600px;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;

border:black;*/
}
li {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:black;
display:inline-block;
}

#red {
background:red;
}
#green{
background:green;
}
#blue {
background:blue;
}
#orange{
background:orange;
}
#purple{
background:purple;
}
#pink {
background:pink;
}
#silver {
background:silver;
}
#gold{
background:gold;
}
#black {
background:black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="grid">
<li alt="red1" class="red"  id='red' ></li>

<a href="http://www.google.com"><li id="orange"></li></a>

<li id="silver"></li>

<li alt="green machine"  id="green"></li>

<li id="gold"></li>

<li id="purple"></li>

<li id="pink" alt="pink"></li>

<li id="blue"></li>

<li id="black"></li>
</ul>
```

**Here's where the problem is**
    
    //Waits until the document loads
    window.onload = function(){
   **Stupid red box says I have too much code, sooo irksome!**
    //Handler for Ul element
    var donut = document.querySelector('#grid');

```
donut.addEventListener('click',function(e){

    //Prevents the href    
    e.preventDefault();
**How do I stop it from selecting the ul tag**
    //Stops it from deleting all squares
    var howmany = this.querySelectorAll('li').length;
        if (howmany > 1 ) {
        console.log(e);
        var removeTarget = e.target;  
        removeTarget.remove(e.target); 
        }
    } 

, false);

/*var tomato = document.getElementById('grid')
tomato.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   console.log("Clicked inside the UL");
   e.preventDefault();} , false);*/

/*var nachos = document.getElementById('pink')
nachos.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.toElement);
    e.stopPropagation();
} , false);*/


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you place this on a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
var donut = document.querySelector('#grid');

donut.addEventListener('click', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
         e.target.remove();
    }
} , false);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/sq48dv7j/**